# Unable to create MIDI connection

Tags: midi

I'm having a problem on my windows machine of recording my MIDI keyboard. I'm currently using a Yamaha, and I have a midi connection from MIDI Output to USB. When I check system devices, my computer sees that I have a USB MIDI keyboard installed. I'm having problems actually recognizing and using the MIDI on a sequencer. I downloaded a piece of software called Anvil Studio's which handels MIDI connections.][1] It doesn't seem to be able to read it. Any suggestions in troubleshooting this. I haven't really ever worked with a MIDI before. 
As you can see, my computer is registering the device.

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]

I have more info on the system. I've managed to get the output to work (now on Linux). Using LMMS I can play notes on my keyboard through my computer. The only thing that still isn't working now is input. My ports are currently

```
 Port     Client name                       Port name
14:0     Midi Through                      Midi Through Port-0
24:0     USB Midi                          USB Midi MIDI 1
128:1     LMMS                              Default preset
128:2     LMMS                              Default preset
128:4     LMMS                              Default preset
129:0     Client-129                        qjackctl
130:0     FLUID Synth (24333)               Synth input port (24333:0)
```

Right now the Output and Input are going through port 24:0 USB Midi on LMMS. I still can't figure out why it wont record.

Comment: So my MIDI in light keeps on blinking but MIDI out is blank.

Comment: I installed MIDI-OX via this tutorial and I keep getting activating sensing, timing clock, and stop via MIDI-OX. What does this mean and why can't I get my input to work.  http://www.native-instruments.com/en/support/knowledge-base/show/998/how-to-monitor-the-input-of-a-midi-controller/

Comment: What kind of [Yamaha device](http://www.yamaha-motor.com/) are you using? How exactly is it connected to the computer; does it have USB-MIDI, or are you using a separate USB/MIDI interface? What is the list of MIDI ports in the sequencer?

Comment: So...after a ton of digging I've managed to get a lot closer though I haven't actually totally solved it yet. I am currently getting MIDI Output to work using LLMS software on Linux ( I switched over systems). The next comment will have more output information.

Comment: Port     Client name                       Port name
 14:0     Midi Through                      Midi Through Port-0
 24:0     USB Midi                          USB Midi MIDI 1
128:1     LMMS                              Default preset
128:2     LMMS                              Default preset
128:4     LMMS                              Default preset
129:0     Client-129                        qjackctl
130:0     FLUID Synth (24333)               Synth input port (24333:0)

Comment: How exactly is the keyboard connected to the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on the problem for a while, I managed to come to the conclusion that it is most likely a hardware defect in the cord. In linux,

```
 aseqdump -p "USB Midi"
```

reported the output

```
24:0   Clock      24:0   Clock      24:0   Clock      24:0   Clock  24:0   Active Sensing  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Stop  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Active Sensing  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Clock  24:0   Stop
```

and aconnect -i and aconnect -o revealed

```
aconnect -i client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]     0 'Timer           '     1 'Announce        ' client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]     0 'Midi Through Port-0' client 28: 'USB Midi' [type=kernel]     0 'USB Midi MIDI 1 '     '
```

and

```
aconnect -o client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]     0 'Midi Through Port-0' client 28: 'USB Midi' [type=kernel]     0 'USB Midi MIDI 1 ' client 128: 'FLUID Synth (3237)' [type=user]     0 'Synth input port (3237:0)'
```

I followed this tutorial to give me some guidance:

tedfelix.com/linux/linux-midi.html

But I could get everything to work only until it began to integrate the hardware with the OS. I'm hoping this isn't a hardware problem, or that it isn't that the output on my keyboard is broken.